# C++ Call function of a temporary object

Tags: c++, function, object, call, temporary

For example:

```
private:
    std::vector<std::string> _content;
public:
    Document (const std::string& path) :_content(FileIO().read(path)) { }
```

Is it OK to call a function `( read() )` directly with an "temporary" `Object ( FileIO() )` ?
I'm asking because it seems very convenient, but I have never seen code like this before. Just want to know if this is "valid" C++ code, rather than some weird anti pattern or performance "no no".

Comment: Not sure, but I think it's valid only if the called method is defined as static

Comment: For me, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you put the definition of FileIO()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fine. `path` is well-defined, and the anonymous temporary will be valid during initialisation of the member `_content`.

You should note that if an exception is thrown by `FileIO().read(path)` then `~Document()` will **not** be called.

Comment: Thanks ! ... and very good to know, that the Destructor is not called in case of an exception

Answer (score 4):

The lifetime of the temporary lasts until the constructor of `_content` returns, so it is valid and safe.

Comment: More formally, to the end of the full expression.